# Courier bold font not correctly rendered when cropping a pdf file on linux

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm extracting pages from a pdf as images with pdfbox 2.0.21 and add them to a word document. When i generate the file on a windows environment the document fonts are rendered correctly, while when running on the test environment (centos 7) they are rendered as from below image [image]

I suspect the pddocument doesn't have the courier bold font, so it defaults to some native set when rendering the images. How could i solve this problem? i don't see any method to force or specify font set.
the code to extract the image is the following

```
        PDDocument document = null;
        try {   
            
            document = PDDocument.load(sourceOfImages);
            
            
            PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
            
            for (int page = 0; page < document.getNumberOfPages(); ++page)
            {
                logger.debug( " page  " + page + "of " + document.getNumberOfPages());
                
                ReportImage reportImage = new ReportImage();
                try (ByteArrayOutputStream pageImagesOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream())
                {

                
                    
                    BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page, DPI, ImageType.RGB);                   

                    logger.debug( " start clear metadata area ");
                    clearImageArea(bim,whiteAreaMetadataX,whiteAreaMetadataY,whiteAreaMetadataW,whiteAreaMetadataH);
                    logger.debug( " end clear metadata area ");

                    
                    logger.debug( " creating png ");
                    final int[] colourMap = {   0x00000000, 0xffffffff, 0xff000000, 0xff353535, 0xff888888, 0xff969696, 0xff237fe9, 0xffff0000 };
                    IndexColorModel colorModel = new IndexColorModel(8, colourMap.length, colourMap, 0, true, 0, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE );
                    
                    
                    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(ReportHelper.getA4W(DPI), ReportHelper.getA4H(DPI), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
                    image.getGraphics().drawImage(bim, 0, 0, null);                 
                    ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", pageImagesOutputStream);
                    
                    double cmWidth = 21;
                    double cmHeight = 29.7;

                    pageImagesOutputStream.flush();
                    logger.debug( "end creating png ");
                    
                    reportImage.setImage(pageImagesOutputStream.toByteArray());
                    reportImage.setWidth(cmWidth);
                    reportImage.setHeight(cmHeight);
                    reportImage.getMetadata().getPDFInfoDTO().setFileName(fileName);
                    reportImage.getMetadata().setPageNumber(page);
                    
                    images.add(reportImage);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.error("failed reading images at page" + page, ex);
                    throw new IOException(ex);
                }
                logger.debug( " end page " + page);
            }
            logger.debug( " end file elaboration " + fileName + " size " + images.size());
            return images;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            logger.error("failed reading document", ex);
            throw new IOException(ex);
        }
```

Comment: Install the mscorefonts  fonts on your machine. And use the latest PDFBox version.

Comment: `image.getGraphics().drawImage` produces a memory leak. You need to `dispose` your graphics object.

Comment: i dispose graphics objects, just didn't post the whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved installing mscorefonts on docker image